# Inserting PHP inside do_shortcode

Tags: shortcode

I am trying to use an existing shortcode for an accordion element in a custom template for my wordpress site. Basically, I need to insert PHP arrays inside this shortcode, like so:

```
<php do_shortcode('[vc_accordion]';>

PHP arrays here

<php do_shortcode('[/vc_accordion]';>
```

Does anyone know if a solution?

Comment: That's not how shortcodes work, you have to pass the entire shortcode into the function

Comment: Right, but I'm looking for a solution that I can insert the rest of the PHP into the function.

Comment: Everything that you pass in to the shortcode has to be done via the shortcode string, I don't think a shortcode is what you should be using for this

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I would use:

```
$open_shortcode = '[vc_accordion]';
$shortcode_data = '';
$close_shortcode = '[/vc_accordion]';

$myarray = array(
    'tabs' => 
        array(
            'title' => 'Section 1',
            'content' => 'Any text here'
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'Section 2',
            'content' => 'Any text here'
        )
);

foreach( $myarray['tabs'] as $tab ){
    $shortcode_data .= '[vc_accordion_tab title="' . $tab['title'] . '"]' . $tab['content'] . '[/vc_accordion_tab]';
}

echo do_shortcode($open_shortcode . $shortcode_data . $close_shortcode);
```

Assuming you want something similar to this:

```
[vc_accordion]
    [vc_accordion_tab title="Section 1"]Any text here[/vc_accordion_tab]
    [vc_accordion_tab title="Section 2"]Any text here[/vc_accordion_tab]
[/vc_accordion]
```

You provided very little detail which doesn't help us help you, but I believe this should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you could simply use a short code and parse the entered value as php by using `eval()`.

That would probably be the answer to your question. Yet I have to ask why? Why do you want to do that.

You can extend your short code and pass variables just there. Parsing php is highly unsafe as there could be a security threat and is just bad practice. The array passed via short code is much better.

Answer (score -1):

This is Correct Format:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( $content ) ?>
```

Example --> Your Short Code : [wp-like-locker]
Now Inster :

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( [wp-like-locker] ) ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: @toscho Edit My Answer

Comment: Now it is invalid PHP. :) Please test your suggestion, and provide an explanation.